# Convert timestamp to date with JS mustache from Algolia in Rails .erb page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mustache, algolia

Hy! Im trying to convert a date in timestamp format inside a script in an .erb file. The timestamp data came directly from Algolia and the code looks like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
     ....
     <p class="hit-name card-text">
     {{{date_stamp}}}
     </p>
     ....
 </script>
```

How can i convert the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transformData` in the widget for that hit. In there you add something like `const date = new Date(date_stamp)` and return it in the object in the end. You can also format it however you want with the regular JS functions there.

See more [in the documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/widgets/hits.html#struct-HitsTransforms)

Comment: Thank you very much...This is my widget, i can't figure out how to implement, can u give me a suggestion? 


  search.addWidget(
    datePicker({
      attributeName: 'date_stamp',
    })
    );